# Statistics probability confidence interval sample mean tomatoes food

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, confidence-interval

To evaluate the effectiveness of a new type of plant food developed for tomatoes, an experiment was conducted in which a random sample of 50 seedlings was obtained from a large greenhouse having thousands of seedlings. Each of the 50 plants received 64 grams of this new type of plant food each week for 16 weeks. The number of tomatoes produced by each plant was recorded yielding the following results:

sample mean X bar = 30.35

standard deviation = 3.945

A researcher has started with a new sample and a given degree of confidence that the average number of tomatoes the seedlings produced on the new plant food is between "37.65289 and 40.00711". Suppose the sample size and standard deviation are the same as given above. What alpha did the researcher use in the construction of this statement?  (Input your answer as a decimal)

I have done the following
using the formula provided by in class

[image]

I isolated for z critical *

After getting z critical *, I looked at the t distributions printed table to find alpha / 2 which was within the 95% confidence interval column.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type out the problem and your work.

Comment: While Bruce's answer is great (+1), I think you may also benefit from reading the steps in general terms on Wikipedia to get an overview (if have not already). Here is a link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval#Basic_steps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your confidence interval is of the following type:

$$\bar X \pm t^*\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}.$$

First, you need to underatand that the margin of error is half the
width of the CI $(37.6589, 40.00711),$ which is
$(40.00711 - 37.6589)/2 =  1.174105.$

Then the margin of error is
$$t^*\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}} = t^*\frac{3.945}{\sqrt{50}} = t^*(0.5579073) = 1.174105,$$

so $t^* = 2.062.$

Now you need to find the confidence level. Sample size $n = 50$ implies
degrees of freedom $n-1 = 49.$ But most t-tables won't have a row for
49 degrees of freedom, and you'll have to use the standard normal approximation instead.
The value 2.062 cuts about 0.5% of the probability from the upper tail
of the standard normal distribution (and also of $\mathsf{T}(49)$.)
So it must be approximately a 99% CI.(To be fussy, maybe 98.8%)

Your work is a little hard to read, but now that I've done it for
myself, I think your only mistake was to use the *whole* width of the CI
in your computation instead of *half* the width, which is the margin
of error. (It is very late here and you should check all of my
computations.)

Comment: Okay thanks this solutiom looks good!  For "What alpha did the researcher use in the construction of this statement? (Input your answer as a decimal)" I put the answer of 99% as 0.99 or 0.988 right?

Comment: You'll have to look at the textbook's definition. maybe it's something like $(1-\alpha)\%,$ in which case it would be $\alpha = .01$. Or I've seen $(1-\alpha/2)\%.$ So check the book carefully.